# Save parcelable class into file

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

I was using a serializable class for I save the xml parser result, but when I read that It is very slow in Android, I changed to parcelable class.

Now, I want to save the content parcelable class into file.

How can I do it?

Thanks. Regards.

Answer (score 22):

According to [Parcel API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class
>   (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects
>   into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As
>   such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent
>   storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data
>   in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

`Parcelable` is meant for `IPC` use only and is not designed to be persisted. So you have to convert your object into some sort of persistable data structures like `XML`, `JSON`, `Serializable`.